# PLS-00049: bad bind variable in UPDATE Trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am trying to write a simple trigger in Oracle 11g Express Edition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_UPDATE 
BEFORE UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.End_Date := SYSDATE;
END;
```

But it raises error:

```
Error(4,1): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.END_DATE'
```

What is the problem with this simple trigger?

Comment: is there a "End_Date" column in table EMPLOYEE?

Comment: Yes it is column in the table Employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow after rewriting CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE statement problem disappeared. I had

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
( "Employee_ID" NUMBER(6,0),
 "HireDate" DATE,
 "Salary" NUMBER(8,2),
 CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYEE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("Employee_ID") ENABLE
 );
```

I deleted table and rewrote CREATE TABLE syntax without double quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
( Employee_ID NUMBER(6,0),
 HireDate DATE,
 Salary NUMBER(8,2),
 CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY (Employee_ID) ENABLE
 );
```

and problem disappeared.

**EDIT:**
As @Sathya explained it's not somehow, in Oracle, an object name, when created with quotes surrounding it's name becomes case sensitive. My misunderstanding was problem.

Comment: with quotes, you hvae to enter the query in quotes with same case as well. Eg. :new."END_Date"= '<value>'. By the way, the table doe not have the END_DATE column?

Comment: it's not *somehow*, in Oracle, an object name, when created with quotes surrounding it's name becomes case sensitive